# Sequelize: same model across multiple databases

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

My application is running on NodeJS and is written in TypeScript (making use of [sequelize-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript) for the DB part). It uses multiple databases because the datasets will grow exponentially, and each database logs specific stuff related to another application.

So I would like my models to be replicated across each database, for instance I have this model:

```js
import { Table, Column, Model, DataType, BelongsTo } from 'sequelize-typescript';

import { AppUser } from './AppUser';

@Table
export class Event extends Model<Event> {

  @Column(DataType.STRING(50))
  category: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING(50))
  action: string;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  value: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING(100))
  label: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => AppUser, 'userId')
  appUser: AppUser;

}
```

It works just fine on one DB instance but I can't add that model to multiple instances.

Is there a way to share the model class across multiple sequelize instances ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Repository Mode?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript#how-to-use-associations-with-repository-mode